# Taylor expansion of a non-Taylor series

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, power-series, taylor-expansion

Show that the following function is arbitrarily differentiable and find its Taylor expansion zero-centered.

$$g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}, \hspace{5mm} g(x):= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(n^2x)}{2^n}.$$

**Solution:**

At the moment, I don't know (with formal proof) if the symbols $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}$, $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}$ switch. I proceed with one of the formal definition of the derivative:

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}(g) = \lim_{x \to x_0} \frac{g(x)-g(x_0)}{x-x_0} = \lim_{x \to x_0} \left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(n^2x)-\cos(n^2x_0)}{2^n(x-x_0)}\right) \hspace{5mm} \text{if the limit exists.}$$

I'm stuck at this point. Also I don't know if the symbols $\lim_{x\to x_0}$ and $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}$ switch. By the way, I tried with the following expansion:

$$\cos:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}, \hspace{5mm} \cos(x):= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k}}{(2k)!} x^{2k}.$$

But I don't see any advantage of use this expansion. I would be grateful for any help/hint.

Comment: Show that your original series is uniformly convergent of $\mathbb R$ (easy). Then you can interchange $d/dx $ and $\sum$. Show that this can be repeated as many times as you wish.

Comment: I think you need the series of derivatives to be uniformly continuous in order to switch $d/dx$ and $\sum$.

Comment: Another idea: write the Taylor series for each term, then (with the right conditions) switch the two summations.

Comment: It's easy to justify infinite differentiability by induction (one needs to show that each successive term by term derivative converges uniformly to infer that the previous level is differentiable with derivative obtained differentiating term by term), while the odd Taylor coefficients at zero are zero and even ones are just $a_{2k}=\pm \sum n^{4k}/2^n$, but the function is not analytic at zero as it is not hard to show that $|a_{2k}|>> \frac {\log^{4k}k}{k}$ so $|a_{2k}|^{1/2k} \to \infty$ and the radius of convergence is zero (original series diverges for any complex non real $x$)